# It is possible to set width of <ons-select> in OnsenUI?

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I want to do something like: ons-select width="100". However, it seems that option is not available in OnsenUI.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style it using css.

```
<ons-select style="width: 100px">
```

Comment: This is what I've been doing:     <div ng-controller='CollectionCtrl'>
        <ons-select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="collection for collection in listCollection" style="width: 100px">
            <option value="">Select collection</option>
        </ons-select>
    </div>